# Apache редирект .htaccess / на .html

Tags: .htaccess, apache, редирект

Помогите составить редирект который работал бы так:

При переходе по ссылке выида `http://site.ru/novosti/{переменная1}/{переменная2}/`
должно произойти перебрасывание на `http://site.ru/novosti/{переменная1}/{переменная2}.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Module mod_alias

```
RedirectMatch "^/novosti/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$" "http://site.ru/novosti/$1/$2.html"
```

Comment: вставил после RewriteEngine On но не работает(

Comment: mod_alias подключен?

Comment: разобрался, правильно будет так: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/novosti/(.*)/(.*)/$ http://site.ru/novosti/$1/$2.html`

Comment: Убрал в ответе из первого параметра адрес сайта.

Comment: еще одна непонятность если нужно сделать перенапровление с `http://site.ru/novosti/{переменная1}/{переменная2}` без слеша в конце, использовал такой код:`RedirectMatch ^/novosti/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /novosti/$1/$2.html` но результат меня удивил и не знаю как его побороть, получилось что у меня в адресной строке очень много .html.html.html получилось, как решить?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect /index.html http://example.com/newdirectory/

Подставьте сюда свои значения.

Приблизительно - так:

Redirect http://site.ru/novosti/{переменная1}/{переменная2}/           http://site.ru/novosti/{переменная1}/{переменная2}.html

Comment: мне нужно сделать это по маске, более 22000 элементов, именно поэтому переменные написаны

Comment: Тогда не знаю, извините)